# Python boolean comparison and is

Tags: python, boolean

Python 3.6.2 console:

```
>>> 11 > 0 is True
False
```

but

```
>>> 0 is True
False
>>> 11 > False
True
```

So, why `11 > 0 is True` is `False`?

Comment: it's `(11>0) and (0 is True)`, I remember there is a dupe somewhere

Comment: This behaviour seems really odd.

Comment: @AaronChristiansen yeah, this one is surprising if you are unaware that chaining applies to all comparison operators, not just `<` and `>` (and their inclusive versions).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The fact that Python can handle expressions like `2 < x < 5` is fantastic, but it feels a bit counterintuitive for `is`.

Comment: @AaronChristiansen I agree. But `is` should certainly be considered a comparison operator, and I'm not sure how I feel about this behavior only applying to *certain* comparison operators. Certainly, reasonable people could disagree. By now I'm just used to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of [comparison chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) since both `>` and `is` are comparison operators.

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent
>   to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both
>   cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).
>
> Formally, if `a, b, c, …, y, z` are expressions and `op1, op2, …, opN` are
>   comparison operators, then `a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z` is equivalent to
>   `a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z`, except that each expression is
>   evaluated at most once.

Thus, it is equivalent to:

```
>>> (11 > 0) and (0 is True)
False
```

Comment: this one never gets old :) it's a duplicate, but hey, not all cases & combinations of `is`, `=`, `<`, `>` isn't covered and OPs don't have a clue of this chaining pattern and fail to see it most of the time. Every one of us should have a duplicate answer of that (I have one :))

Comment: This particular case may take the prize for most naturally confusing combination though. `11 > 0 is True` is a nice sentence.