# Why does a Python "x in xyz" comparison not yield equality when it returns True by itself?

Tags: python-3.x, boolean

With these statements:

```
>>> "foo" in "foobar"
True
>>> "foo" in "foobar" is True
False
>>> ("foo" in "foobar") is True
True
```

Why is the second statement not returning `True`?

Comment: [Comparison chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) - `"foo" in "foobar" is True` -> `("foo" in "foobar") and ("foobar" is True)` -> `True and False` -> `False`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/49893766/3001761

Comment: Okay, wow. This is super unintuitive for the `in` comparative. So it helps to think of this as akin to a `0 < 5 < 10` comparison, correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly - that chaining happens for _all_ comparison operators.